# In osclass change http://domainname/user/profile/1 to http://domainname/username, is it possible?

Tags: php, .htaccess, osclass

Hi I am using osclass and to look any user profile I have to go to this url
With permalink enabled

http://domainname/user/profile/1

Is it possible to view user profile with this url

http://domainname/username

With simple permalink changes ?or I have to change the code for this?

Please let me know how to do it.

Comment: You'll definitely have to change the code for it, since now you're looking for a username instead of an ID.

Comment: Do you have any idea how to do it?

Comment: I assume you have some RewriteRule in your .htaccess document redirecting the visitor to some .php page where the ID is a get variable. In this page this ID is used to get the correct user from the database. What you want to do is change the RewriteRule to work with the username url, and change the database look up to search for the username instead of an ID.

Answer (score 0):

First, for a user whose id is 42, you can let that user choose a username (that's a feature in Osclass) so both these URLs will point to the same page:

- `http://domain.com/user/profile/42`
- `http://domain.com/user/profile/myowncustomusername`

Now about changing 'user/profile', you need to head to the admin, `Settings > Permalinks` where you can change the rules used for routing/rewriting URLs.

You have **two problems** though:

1. URLs like `http://domain.com/something` are used for search and category (have a nice URLs for all your categories). The modification will mess up with that behavior.
2. Osclass doesn't allow you to save an empty Rewrite rule in admin.

I can get you started but I think that trying to change it might work but will need a lot of testing and headaches. If you ask me, it's not worth the hassle.

**To deal with the first problem,**

You'll need to modify the search controller to look for user with username `something` first, before looking for a category named `something`.

Look in `/oc-includes/osclass/controller/search.php` around line 78.

**To deal with the second problem,**

You could change that if-block:

```
if(!osc_validate_text($rewrite_user_profile)) {
   $errors += 1;
} else {
   osc_set_preference('rewrite_user_profile', $rewrite_user_profile);
}
```

by:

```
osc_set_preference('rewrite_user_profile', $rewrite_user_profile);
```

in the file `/oc-admin/controller/settings/permalinks.php` around line 245.

Answer (score 0):

There is a way to change this url using phpmyadmin

go to phpmyadmin and inside the relevant database find the table name oc-t-preference. there you find the field called 'rewrite_user_profile' the default value would be 'user/profile'. you can change this to what is needed like 'shop' or leave empty. thats fine your expectation is ready.